# How do you change the filtering mode of images in a Flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, image, filtering

I have an `Image` control in my Flex application:

```
<mx:Image id="img" source="@Embed('img.png')"
          percentHeight="100" percentWidth="100"  />
```

Because the image is scaled, there are a lot of scaling artifacts. Can I change the image to use a different type of filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and set `smoothBitmapContent="true"` on the image control, that should improve image quality.